# How to make regular javascript work in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I was trying to implement this text scrable
https://codepen.io/soulwire/pen/mErPAK/?editors=1010
in my react app, but I'm receiving an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null.

```
   9 |   this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  10 | }
  11 | setText(newText) {
> 12 |   const oldText = this.el.innerText
  13 |   const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
  14 |   const promise = new Promise(resolve => (this.resolve = resolve))
  15 |   this.queue = []
```

so far this is what I did
https://codesandbox.io/s/oxm38v7x9y

1. Created new component scrable.js
2. Moved the code from codepen
3. Imported to index.js

you don't need to fix the codesandbox, just a little clue is enough :)

```
import React, { Component } from "react"

export default class Scrable extends Component {
  render() {
    const phrases = [
      "Neo,",
      "sooner or later",
      "you're going to realize",
      "just as I did",
      "that there's a difference",
      "between knowing the path",
      "and walking the path",
    ]
    const el = document.querySelector(".text")
    const fx = new TextScramble(el)
    console.log(el)
    let counter = 0
    const next = () => {
      fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
        setTimeout(next, 800)
      })
      counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
    }
    next()
    return (
      <TextScramble>
        <div className="text" />
      </TextScramble>
    )
  }
}

export class TextScramble extends Component {
  constructor(el) {
    super()
    this.el = el
    this.chars = "!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________"
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise(resolve => (this.resolve = resolve))
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ""
      const to = newText[i] || ""
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ""
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
  render() {
    return <div />
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you declaring a class _inside_ the render function? O_o That makes no sense, classes are their own thing. Move that out of render, and put it at the same level as your `class Scrable extends Component`. Classes are a top level construct.

Comment: hmm.. I have no idea, can I just convert it to a regular function instead?

Comment: right! I'll try that one out. thanks!

Comment: I'm not trying to sound mean but i recommend starting again with a basic tutorial on React and its concepts. The way you are using it is all kinds of wrong. Don't try to query for dom nodes with query selector and classes. Instead use your render function and display the things you want.

Comment: thanks' thats okay no worries. that's what I'm doing now

Comment: Basically in React `document.querySelector` and setting innerText `this.el.innerText` is a no-no.

Comment: Thanks all I was able to fix it :) @xDreamCoding I will post my answer below any suggestions is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hi all thank you for the comments,

I was able to make it work. here's my code below. any suggestions is welcome

I'm not entirely sure it's the right way but it works

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Scrable extends Component {
  constructor(el) {
    super(el)
    this.el = el
    this.chars = "!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________"
    // this.update = this.update.bind(this)
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    const phrases = [
      'Neo,',
      'sooner or later',
      'you\'re going to realize',
      'just as I did',
      'that there\'s a difference',
      'between knowing the path',
      'and walking the path'
    ]

    const el = document.querySelector('.text')
    const fx = new TextScramble(el)

    let counter = 0
    const next = () => {
      fx.setText(phrases[counter]).then(() => {
        setTimeout(next, 800)
      })
      counter = (counter + 1) % phrases.length
    }

    next()
    console.log(el)
  }
  render() {
    const phrases = [
      "Neo,",
      "sooner or later",
      "you're going to realize",
      "just as I did",
      "that there's a difference",
      "between knowing the path",
      "and walking the path",
    ]

    return (
      <div>
        <div className="text">text</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class TextScramble {
  constructor(el) {
    this.el = el
    this.chars = '!<>-_\\/[]{}—=+*^?#________'
    this.update = this.update.bind(this)
    console.log(this)
  }
  setText(newText) {
    const oldText = this.el.innerText
    const length = Math.max(oldText.length, newText.length)
    const promise = new Promise((resolve) => this.resolve = resolve)
    this.queue = []
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      const from = oldText[i] || ''
      const to = newText[i] || ''
      const start = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      const end = start + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40)
      this.queue.push({ from, to, start, end })
    }
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.frameRequest)
    this.frame = 0
    this.update()
    return promise
  }
  update() {
    let output = ''
    let complete = 0
    for (let i = 0, n = this.queue.length; i < n; i++) {
      let { from, to, start, end, char } = this.queue[i]
      if (this.frame >= end) {
        complete++
        output += to
      } else if (this.frame >= start) {
        if (!char || Math.random() < 0.28) {
          char = this.randomChar()
          this.queue[i].char = char
        }
        output += `<span class="dud">${char}</span>`
      } else {
        output += from
      }
    }
    this.el.innerHTML = output
    if (complete === this.queue.length) {
      this.resolve()
    } else {
      this.frameRequest = requestAnimationFrame(this.update)
      this.frame++
    }
  }
  randomChar() {
    return this.chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.chars.length)]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't want to listen that's fine. But u said any suggestions are welcome so i'll tell you again don't use React like that. You aren't supposed to use `querySelector` and set `innerText` of an html element like that. Although it might work that's not what React was build for and doesn't utilise Reacts strengths. Explaining Reacts inner workings is too much for a comment or answer here so i'll recommend again going over a basic tutorial of React and its concepts.